# C# SQLDataAdapter - Will different command connections render unexpected results?

Tags: c#, dataset, sqldataadapter

Let's say you have a single SQLdataAdapter that has Insert, Select, Delete and Update commands. Each of these SQL commands has a connection property. Does anyone know if by setting the connection properties to different sql connections/sources will have adverse affects down the road?

So if sqlAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = "Database1". While sqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Connection = "Database2".

I haven't found anything online that supports or opposes this.

Please note - I don't not have the above explicitly defined in my code. This is for the sake of example.

Thx

Comment: For sake of example create a demo and check it out.

Comment: the demo is what brought me here to ask this question. i haven't seen anything documented on the above question therefore i came to ask.

Comment: Nothing? I'm wondering if this is just not a very common practice so therefore no one is touching this.. lol